# Is there an equivalence of 'android.os.AsyncTask' in java or I just use 'Thread#sleep'?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, thread-sleep

I am trying to develop an application that is already exist but for android OS. I faced a class that extends `android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`, because java does not have this class.

What I want is to do some functions in the background like this class do I think. So is there a thread or any class for that purpose or I just use `Thread.sleep()` method?

Comment: Your title is misleading, asynctask in google is used for networking stuff, Thread.sleep is putting your current thread to the blockstate

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: Thanks for the good information. You're right it's for networking stuffs, what shall I do about that?

Comment: What does `sleep` have to do with running tasks in the background?

Comment: @immibis: I thought that it does, but as #Rod said Thread is running tasks in background. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Network operations are only one of many uses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be wise to make your own Thread as a `backgroundTask` like in android's `AsyncTask`.

**sample:**

```
Thread d = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do background task here
        }
    });

    d.start(); //start the background task
```

Comment: This is extremely different from an AsyncTask - about the only thing in common is that the work is done on a different thread.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes you are right, but I was answering Op's "I want is to do some functions in the background"